# Get the number of points in a line with consideration for a minimum/maximum segment

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out the formula to calculate the number of holes that are required along some distance.
The distances are from 500mm to 6000mm.
The left and right sides have a hole 50mm from each side.
Off the remainder, will need to figure out how many holes are required, when the distance between each hole has the be anywhere between 400mm and 500mm, and one hole in the middle of the length
anyone have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: On a length of say 600 mm (anything smaller than 900 has the same issue), if you have one hole 50mm from each end and another hole in the middle, then the distance between these three holes is only 250 mm, which does not fall in the given range.

Comment: Assuming the length $l$ is at least $900$, maybe you're looking for "$2n + 1$ where $n$ is an integer between $(l - 100)/1000$ and $(l-100)/800$"?